# Jest Custom Test Environment Can't Use Absolute Paths

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I can't import absolute paths in a Jest custom test environment. Simplified repo here: https://github.com/kyle-banner/ts-customtestenvironment-jest

Run `yarn int` and you'll see an error

```
 FAIL  path/to/test/something.integration.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'src/config'
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution to this [as suggested by the Jest team](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11911) is to [self-reference a package using its name](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_self_referencing_a_package_using_its_name). I have updated the [example repository](https://github.com/kyle-banner/ts-customtestenvironment-jest) to reflect this solution.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-proj",
  ...
  "exports": {
    ".": "./index.js",
    "./serverConfig": "./src/config/index.ts"
  }
}
```

testEnvironment.ts

```
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node');
// @ts-ignore
import serverConfig from 'test-proj/serverConfig';

class CustomEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  constructor(config, context) {
    super(config, context);
  }

  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    this.global.someGlobalObject = serverConfig;
  }

  async teardown() {
    await super.teardown();
  }
}

module.exports = CustomEnvironment;
```